# Configure make gnome commander - no glib 2.6.0

Tags: linux, redhat, configure, glib

Trying to install gnome commander on **RHEL 7.4**

Already went past some missing dependencies during `./configure` however I'm stuck on this `error` :

> checking if glib >= 2.6.0 exists... configure: error: no

`sudo yum install glib` does not find anything, I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to compile a program by yourself then dependent library sources have to be available on the target system. The names of these library source packages often contain the suffix "-devel". So try to install the glibc sources via

```
sudo yum install glibc-devel
```

There might come up other dependency issues, but they can be solved with the same strategy.

Comment: Yeah, i did that already. 

Package glibc-devel-2.17-222.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Still configure fails:
checking if glib >= 2.6.0 exists... configure: error: no